# Tags included from libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` folder stopped working after update to Jetty 9.2.2.v20140723

Tags: jetty, jsp-tags, maven-jetty-plugin

I updated Jetty (and Jetty Maven plugin) from `9.2.1.v20140609` to `9.2.2.v20140723` and now this exception is thrown when I try to access any webpage of my application:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/(...).jsp (line: 2, column: 0)
The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved
in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

Currently I use

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" prefix="security"%>
```

in top of all JSP files and Spring Security tags are included in WAR file:

[image: ROOT.war content]

When I extract `*.tld` file from JAR, put in `WEB-INF` and manually include it using

```xml
<jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>security.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

in `web.xml`, it start working again. But I will have to do it for all tags from all libraries...

Seems that Jetty somehow stopped scanning `WEB-INF/lib` for `*.tld` files. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

In `pom.xml` I had

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- (...) --->
        <contextXml>${basedir}/path/to/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>-->
        <!-- (...) --->
    <configuration>
</plugin>
```

and in `jetty-context.xml` I had

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="maxFormKeys">8000</Set>
    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>.*/.*jsp-api-[^/]\.jar$|./.*jsp-[^/]\.jar$|./.*taglibs[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

I **removed** both `<contextXml>` from POM and `jetty-context.xml` and everything is working again.